# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on loading my WP app

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, dns, mcafee

I have hosted my WP app in AWS EC2 and is using GoDaddy DNS to point it to my domain. I received and email from GoDaddy stating that my site is blacklisted by McAfee as Malicious. Please see the image:

[image]

Now, when I try to access my website Google shows an error page with the following content : `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. Is this because my site is blocked due to the McAfee blacklisting. Any help on this is highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` means that your domain is no longer pointing to your server. 
to troubleshoot you may use these steps:

1. check your domain resolve status via this tool https://dnschecker.org
2. if NOT resolved at all register a Cloudflare account then change name servers in your registrar panel to NS provided by cloudflare.
3. make sure that all DNS entries are like original zone.
4. wait for propagation and recheck https://dnschecker.org
5. restart your home router and run this command on windows CMD `ipconfig /flusdns`
6. if you are on Debian/Ubuntu run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution to fix [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/resolve-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-in-linux/) issues.

Release and Renew IP Address

Restart DNS Client Service

Change DNS Servers

Reset Your Browser

Disable VPN and Antivirus Temporarily

try this post for complete info:- [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://medium.com/trinitytuts/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-fix-34c9d6c701aa)